# grab value from an input to use in another div

Tags: javascript, jquery

i was able to do what i needed via clone and insert after but that was creating a duplicate name when submitting the form.

id like to grab the value from this:

```
<input name="something" type="text" value="CASE0000622" maxlength="100" id="csg_name" class="something"/>
```

to be inserted after "Case ID" here (dynamically)

```
<div class='intro'><span id='modID' class='modID'>Case ID </span><span class='modName'></span></div>
```

i have tried this

```
$("#csg_name").value($("#modID").html());
```

via jquery

any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.text()` to set the text content of an element and `.val()` to read the value of an input.

```js
$('.modName').text($('#csg_name').val());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="something" type="text" value="CASE0000622" maxlength="100" id="csg_name" class="something"/>
<div class='intro'><span id='modID' class='modID'>Case ID </span><span class='modName'></span></div>
```

Comment: how about adding that after "case id" instead of replacing it

Comment: @bstime It doesn't replace "Case ID". It's setting the text content of the span right after it (with class "modName"). You can see that by running the snippet in my answer.

Comment: yea i see that im ty, actually lookin to use this on modID class or id but would like it to come after the content "case id" i used what you sent like this:  $('.modID').text($('#csg_name').val()); which is replacing the text "Case ID"  instead of appending the value afterwards

Comment: @bstime You can use `$('.modID').text('Case ID ' + $('#csg_name').val());`